Are there efficiency gains with quiet supersonic technology?
I was reading about the Nasa X-59 a low supersonic noise test aircraft which is nearing the start of flight testing, and it occurred to me that I don't understand the relationship between sonic boom creation, drag and other aspects of aerodynamics. Specifically, I am curious as to whether decreasing sonic boom has any impact on drag, and whether a shape that reduces boom may also reduce the fuel consumption required for supersonic flight.

Weaker shockwaves will reduce the amount of drag on the aircraft (unless in some very specific circumstances). Shockwaves cause a pressure jump, and if that pressure jump is on the front of the aircraft then that will cause a pushing force backwards. (Posting this as a comment because it doesn’t 100% answer your question)

Not really. It can be a side effect, but not the primary goal.
QSST research is primarily focused on directing most of the sonic boom upwards, avoiding impact on the ground. Weakening the boom itself, by making the aircraft closer to a more elongated Sears-Haack body, is one way to do it, and that also decreases drag, but it's only one of the ways used.
The lowest-drag shape is a thin spindle with full-length delta wings. Low sonic boom shapes try to keep a flatter bottom to spread out the impact.
If you consider drag per passenger, the complex shapes used in QSST research are likely to increase it above that of the Concorde, the Tu-144, or even the hypothetical Boeing 2707, since they can fit much fewer people in a similar-sized plane. Older SST projects were about "how can we make a supersonic plane economical for the public", new ones are about "how can we make supersonic flight permitted over land at all?"
Overall, the idea of public supersonic travel is in less demand now. The rest of the world failed to keep up with the advent of Mach 0.7 travel, much less supersonic. On almost any air trip today, one spends more time packing, driving to the airport, standing in lines, waiting for boarding, boarding, waiting for the plane to take off, and then the same in reverse, than actually flying.
That and reliable video conferencing make flight speed less relevant for most traveling public. even for the relatively well-off. Supersonic L/D will always be lower than subsonic, like a best-case of 7:1 vs 20:1. So it will always consume a lot more fuel and cost more.
The result is that modern supersonic transport research is aimed at low-volume private supersonic jets for the 0.0001%, not at large mass-produced aircraft. And smaller size, in itself, makes low sonic boom flight a lot more attainable. Fuel consumption is important so far as lower fuel flow allows for more range.

Fine answer! I might add that the elongated body will increase mass and, therefore, the need for lift creation. That in itself will cause stronger shocks, unfortunately in the downward direction.

Very nice answer

Thinking about this, I would think that having a plane deflect the shockwave downward would generate lift, and deflecting it upward would generate reverse lift.

Most of the things that cause sonic boom also cause drag, so reducing sonic boom and reducing drag are correlated in first order effects.
However, when it comes to subtleties, this is not the case.  An optimum shape from the perspective of sonic boom is not an optimum shape for drag.
So, the X-59 will be pretty low drag -- but not as low drag as it would be if the experiment was to fly the aircraft with the lowest drag instead of fly an aircraft with a tailored boom footprint that meets certain noise requirements.
